# search from json datasource through jsp and servlets

Tags: json, jsp, search, servlets

How to search from Json data source through Jsp and Servlets. Sorry for the question being too broad and not adhering to Stack Overflow rules, Yet kindly help me if u can. Any web-links/ links of tutorials would be helpful. Thank you !

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question , probably this part `search from Json data source `

Comment: @san krish :So, basically I cannot use a database for the search process, so I thought of using Json for storing data and a search box which would search from this datasource. So , I want that when user searches for a thing it should look in the Json file and retrieve few details on the JSP page. I want it to be done via Jsp and servlets. So, kindly you help me !

Comment: you can generate json at runtime after the keyword is searched from DB then use it .

Answer (score 1):

This is a good blog about JSON with JSP & Servlets. [JSON-JSP-SERVLETS](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/creating-parsing-json-data-with-java-servlet-struts-jsp-json/)

And if you are looking for particular search functionily with JSON. Use AJAX and parse JSON response from ajax and it will be easy to use and fast too.

Comment: :Thank you for the link ! You mentioned how AJAX can be used and JSON response can be parsed. So can u just send a few links to me for this, please ! I basically want to implement a search functionality which would look into Json file (as I am told not to use a database for search process) and then retrieve results(here I want the output to be in a grid format) I am using Jsp and servlets. So any good tuturial would be highly benefial for me. I am newbie, so I would be extremely thankful if you can provide me with some helpful links for the same. Thanks in advance !

Comment: @user3444944 If you want to parse JSON file with AJAX. Here is the function that you can refer. [ajax function](http://runnable.com/UhY_jE3QH-IlAAAP/how-to-parse-a-json-file-using-jquery)